# Visual Studio 2008/2010: show method names in Find In Files results

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I had a dream I could see constructor/method/property names along with search results (Visual Studio *Find In Files* feature), if applicable/available.

For example, if I searched for `_dreamProvider` in *Sleep.cs*, I would get something like that in *Find Results* window:

> **Sleep.cs(5):** protected IDreamProvider
>   _dreamProvider;
>
> **Sleep.cs(10): *Sleep(IDreamProvider)*:**
>   _dreamProvider = dreamProvider;
>
> **Sleep.cs(68): *BeginColdSweats(int)*:** var d =
>   _dreamProvider.Create(DreamTypes.Nightmare);
>
> **Sleep.cs(74): *BeginSomniloquy(int,
>   string)*:** var d =
>   _dreamProvider.Create(DreamTypes.Epic);

This could come quite handy if you want to see at a glance in which contexts a code fragment (not only a particular symbol) is used, specifically during analysis of legacy code and/or refactoring.

I could not find any VS addin which would bring that code structure awareness in search results. And there is no specific **[customization registry flag](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/03/customize-how-search-results-are-displayed-in-the-find-results-window.aspx)** for that.

Do you know of any VS addins, or some kind of hacks in order to achieve that or something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReSharper offers this type of "Find Usages..." functionality:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/UsageSearch/findResultsWindow.html

Comment: does it allow to search any text fragment, not only code symbols (like SolutionBase, IsTestShell or FormatSettings as seen on screenshots)?

Comment: Yes it does. You can choose an option "Find Usages Advanced..." from the VS context menu (if ReSharper is installed, of course) where you can specify "Textual occurrences" as one of the "Find" options.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

[Searching and Navigating Code in Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vseditor/archive/2009/09/22/searching-and-navigating-code-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

> Navigate To (Ctrl+comma), new for
>   Visual Studio 2010, is a powerful way
>   to search, especially when you’re not
>   sure exactly what you’re looking for.
>   It helps you locate items in your code
>   by using "fuzzy" search capabilities.
>   For example, if you type Foo Bar
>   instead of FooBar, Navigate To will
>   still return useful results. It’s a
>   smart, incremental search that refines
>   as you type and will find any symbols
>   (e.g. file, type, and member names)
>   matching your search terms.

Comment: unfortunately, it searches for symbols only, not any text fragment (e.g., 'result == "ok"')

Comment: @Maxim, I didn't know that but at least *one of us* has learned something <g>.

Answer (score 2):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does this